# Why I can't download file from FTP using WebClient in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am makind a simple app in VisualStudio2019 with Xamarin.Forms that will download data from ftp server and show it in my app.
All works fine until I try to use mobile data on DUAL SIM phone. On 1 sim it works fine, on Wi-Fi it works fine, but on sim nr 2 it doesn't want to download the file.

On sim 1 the IP is like 100.50.65.43

On sim 2 the IP is like 192.0.0.7 and 2a00:d58:87dd89ee:5g6h:d9h4:qw54:5560

On Wi-Fi the IP is like 192.168.1.75 and ht98::56n1:78gg:tr5h:j657

I have the INTERNET PERMISSION and NETWORK PERMISSION in android manifest.

Here is the code that I use to download the file:

{
string localFile = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SqLiteData.db3");

```
        string ftpUsername = "Login";
        string ftpPassword = "Pass";
        var client = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
            client.DownloadFile("ftp://xxx/SqLiteData.db3", localFile);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            DisplayAlert(null, "not working", "ok");
        }

    }
```

Comment: when it does not work are you getting an exception?  What is the specific exception?  Without any more data it seems likely that the network provider for Sim 2 is blocking FTP traffic.

Comment: I already change the sim order and that is not it. I guess that it has something to do with the IP of the second sim slot, but I can't find the solution for that enywhere.

Comment: you still haven't provided any detail about what "doesn't work" means.  Are you getting an error or exception?  You are catching an exception but ignoring the actual exception object, so your code will not capture any useful detail about what caused the exception.

Comment: here is the system message:

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError () [0x00008] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0
  at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x001b0] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits (System.Net.WebRequest request, System.IO.Stream writeStream) [0x000e6] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0

Comment: at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.Uri address, System.String fileName) [0x00088] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.String address, System.String fileName) [0x00008] in <5c04a0efacc74d5eb8ee45bbf98b24e5>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(string,string)
  at XamarinSqliteTut.HomePage.pobierzDane () [0x00034] in <63254bcd60e442d0bba0342b5cf836a4>:0

Comment: I also checked NetworkAccess using Xamarin.Essentials and in all cases it has access to the Internet.